# How to convert list of keyed 2-lists to list of same-keyed N-lists?

Tags: python

How can I create a list of lists with first element as key:

From:

```
myList = [ [26, 'hello'], [26, 'hola'], [26, 'hi'], [26, 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye'],[27, 'doei'], [27, 'see you'], [27, 'tot ziens'] ]
```

To:

```
[ [26, 'hello', 'hola', 'hi', 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens'] ]
```

Comment: Is the input always sorted by the first list item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to group your values with regard to a key, it is probably not a `list` you are looking for as output, but a `dict`. This will later allow for constant time lookup.

```
myList = [[26, 'hello'], [26, 'hola'], [26, 'hi'], [26, 'bonjour'],
          [27, 'bye'], [27, 'doei'], [27, 'see you'], [27, 'tot ziens']]

myDict = {}

for k, v in myList:
    myDict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(myDict)
```

#### Output

```
{26: ['hello', 'hola', 'hi', 'bonjour'], 27: ['bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens']}
```

Although if you absolutely need a list of lists, you can then obtain it like so:

```
# Only valid in Python3, use [k] + v in Python2
listOfLists = [[k, *v] for k, v in myDict.items()]

print(listOfLists)
```

#### Output

```
[[26, 'hello', 'hola', 'hi', 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens']]
```

Comment: But the OP wants a list of lists, not a dict of lists?

Comment: @DYZ I am suggesting that a dict of lists is better for what OP wants.

Comment: Just a note: `[k, *v]` is only valid in Py3.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier for the quick and detailed response. It did the job.

Comment: @gary Glad I could help, don't forget that you can accept answers that solved your problem. This is even more appreciated than a thank you and helps future user find good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.groupby` and a list comprehension

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> myList = [ [26, 'hello'], [26, 'hola'], [26, 'hi'], [26, 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye'],[27, 'doei'], [27, 'see you'], [27, 'tot ziens'] ]
>>> [[k] + [e[1] for e in grps] for k,grps in groupby(myList, itemgetter(0))]
[[26, 'hello', 'hola', 'hi', 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens']]
```

Comment: You must sort a list by the future grouping key before using `groupby`. Luckily, the list in the original post is sorted, but if it is not, `groupby` would give a wrong answer.

Comment: First, how do you know? Did you ask the OP? Second, your remark is rude and does not belong on SO.

Comment: I believe the OP has given a minimal sample of how his data would look like

Comment: It never hurts to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this solution, which is not optimized but easily readable:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList = [ [26, 'hello'], [26, 'hola'], [26, 'hi'], [26, 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye'],[27, 'doei'], [27, 'see you'], [27, 'tot ziens'] ]

d = defaultdict(list)
for [k,v] in myList:
     d[k].append(v)
newList = [[k,*v] for k,v in d.items()]

print(newList)  # [[26, 'hello', 'hola', 'hi', 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses a nested comprehension:

```
[[y, *[x[1] for x in myList if x[0]==y]] for y in set([z[0] for z in myList])]
```

Output:

```
[[26, 'hello', 'hola', 'hi', 'bonjour'], [27, 'bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens']]
```

Answer (score -1):

The most pythonic way is to group the similar items with `itertool.groupby`. Before grouping, the list must be sorted by the same key that will be used for grouping.

```
from itertools import groupby

[([key] + [word for _, word in words]) for key, words 
   in groupby(sorted(myList), key=lambda x: x[0])]
#[[26, 'bonjour', 'hello', 'hi', 'hola'], 
# [27, 'bye', 'doei', 'see you', 'tot ziens']]
```

By the way, lists do not have keys. (But dictionaries do.)

Comment: Would any of the three downvoters explain what they think is wrong with this solution?

Comment: Great answer! +1. SQL groupby is the first thing which came to mind when I saw this question. One thing worth noting however is that the `dict` based solution are `O(n)` <s>whereas this one in `O(n log(n))` because of the call to `sorted`</s>. **EDIT**: this is actually `O(n)` if the input is sorted because TimSort runs in linear time for sorted input.

Comment: @DYZ At first I disagreed because it does not point out to OP that a dict is a better structure. Although, this is not worth a downvote in my opinion. What made me dowvote is that sorting is O(n log(n)) while using a dictionary uses a single traversal and is O(n). In conclusion: using sorting is not an efficient solution at all.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon See Lakshay Garg's comment on sorting above.

Comment: @DYZ As you commented under other answers, we should not assume the input will always be sorted.